# Out Of memory issue

Tags: android, out-of-memory

OOM issue with device 16M Heap size working (with low resolution 200*200) images in grid view?
I had came across lazy loading  solution,but how to work with drawables & apply lazyloading process to them?
Device with 32M Heap size working fine.
Can anyone advice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can give it a try not sure though : you will have to add in manifest this property within application tag largeheap=true to enable large heap for your app.

Comment: Of course,but it  will up to some extent to avoid OOM  issue

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at the following thread.

[Any best third party tool to cache image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382939/any-best-third-party-tool-to-cache-image-in-android/31383415#31383415)

Just use any of the above Image loaders to achieve what you need.

Comment: I approached all the possible solutions(Picasso,glide) with 12(200*200) images but OOM issue with Emulators 16(VM Heap Size) only.