# Android Image Gallery Memory Use Theory

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery

So, I've been researching on bitmap scaling using the bitmap factory.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I'm doing so because the application I'm working on requires a gallery that allows users to submit their photos to be added to the gallery. These photos will then be read from a URL.

My theoretical problem is this: Considering the android devices can have as low as 16MB of memory, even scaling down the images is only delaying the inevitable unless only handling a single image. Whereas in my case, the amount of images that will be loaded could be hundreds. Meaning that even if they're scaled down, eventually one will reach that limit.

My only idea thus far are to load one image at a time, which is not preferable since users will have to wait between photo transitions.

That being said, is there anyone who has experience developing applications on android that handle 100's of images? If so, is there any theory you could share on handling all these images fluidly? It can obviously be done, as there are gallery applications available. I am just unsure how they accomplished it given the restraints.

**Please note this is not a request on how to use the bitmap factory to scale images, as that question has been answered many times.**

**Rather a request on handling data amounts you know will exceed limitations.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gallary apps should not be storing all thousands of images in memory. Use the Viewholder pattern such that the image views displayed will get recycled (this is forced upon you if you use RecyclerView). On backend use an image cache and keep a limit on it size.

See e.g. [What is the benefit of ViewHolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501316/what-is-the-benefit-of-viewholder)  and [How to release memory of bitmap using imageloader in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341833/how-to-release-memory-of-bitmap-using-imageloader-in-android)

The Android gallary app source may be a good reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/android-5.1.1_r18/src/com/android/camera